# Why does my cat lick his mirror reflection?

Tags: cats, behavior

I have a cat we got from the ASPCA a few years ago, and he's always been very strange for a cat. But I've been noticing that he'll lick his reflection on any glass surface. Why does he do this?

Comment: Interesting. Never seen that particular behavior in a cat. My guess is he sees "another" cat and is "grooming" it. Perhaps separated from from mother and litter mates very early and developed this behavior as a substitute for normal interactions with other cats. Does he also "groom" stuffed animals or fabric?

Answer (score 4):

Very few animals understand that a reflection is themselves, they think it's another animal. It could be that he's trying to groom his "friend".

If there is dew/moisture on the glass he could be getting water from it.

He may just like the texture of it, some cats will lick plastic wrappers for this reason.